# tcpdump capturing packets only when interface is specified

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have tried 3 different ways of capturing a stream of packets coming into my server.  Two of them work and the third does not.  I am trying to determine why it is missed by the third approach:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 udp port 5052
tcpdump -i eth1 -p udp port 5052
tcpdump -i any udp port 5052
tcpdump udp port 5052 #Does not work
```

My theory was that the any approach was failing because the capture was non-promiscuous and it must be getting dropped by iptables somewhere.  However, even when I make the first capture non-promiscuous (by explicitly setting -p) it captures the packets.  What else could be different between the two?

UPDATE: I realized that I was not doing exactly what I thought.  There are actually 4 variations and the one that is failing is only when I don't specify an interface.  What would be different between no `-i` flag and `-i any`?

Comment: With no -i flag, tcpdump will use the first network - this might not be  what you want (eth0 in your case)

Comment: Ah, yes, that would indeed explain the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you start `tcpdump`, it tells you which interface it listens on:

`# tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes`

The manual page is very clear about the matter:

> -i     Listen on interface.  If unspecified, tcpdump searches the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback).  Ties are broken by choosing the earliest match.

This means that as long as you have a configured `eth0` interface, `eth1` will never be selected as default capture interface.

Comment: ...is it just me, or is that a hilariously useless default behavior?